# Turning on colours in vim is not working for some files

Tags: vim, colors, vimrc

My *.vimrc* file is as follows:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on               " enables syntax, e.g. text colour
set number              " show line numbers
```

The command I use to open files is *vim filename*.  Despite this when I open some files I get all the nice fancy colours in my files whereas I have some files that I can't get the colours to work at all.  For example, when I'm editing my *.vimrc* file the syntax works.  When I'm editing another file (called *filename.usr* - it's just a text file) the syntax doesn't work.

Do you know why this is the case and how I can get the syntax to work correctly for all my files?

Comment: What "syntax" do you expect a file named `filename.usr` to have?  What words mean something special depends on what the file is used for -- it's not going to highlight any arbitrary file.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand, thank you.  How would I go about, then, giving the .usr file the characteristics to highlight different expressions?  Or to give it those of another file type?

Comment: The syntax definition files which may be installed somewhere under `share/vim/vim*/syntax/*` may be of interest. I guess for a unknown file type one could go all Jackson Pollack and spray colors everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat files ending in `.usr` like some other type of file (e.g., like a vimrc file), then you can add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.usr setlocal filetype=vim
```

Then, when you open files ending in `.usr`, vim will apply the given filetype's syntax highlighting.